# Keyboard.press only working once with threads python

Tags: python, multithreading, visual-studio-code, macros, keyboard

I've been working on a small script in python to press some keys when I press one specific (I created a macro).
All works fine since I try to use it in any other application like for example a videogame or other programs.

The problem is that it only executes once, and then the only way it executes again is chainging to my IDE tab (Visual studio code) and returning back to the application, and this is quite annoying.

Any idea about it and how to solve that window problem? Here is the code

```
def macros():   
t=threading.Timer(0.1,macros)
t.start()
if keyboard.is_pressed('k'):  
     keyboard.press('e')
     keyboard.press('q')
     print("active")
```

Comment: Could you provide us with an example that can minimize the recurrence of this problem?

Comment: execute the code -> go to any full screen program/game -> the code only works once

Comment: -Have you tried to put the matching button options into a loop to make the code continue to execute?

Comment: well it's already in a loop as it's  a thread executing itself every 0.1s, but i'm gonna try looping only the keypress condition

Comment: well, still not working

Comment: According to the current information, we cannot reproduce this problem. It is recommended that you test whether the code meets your needs in the Python terminal outside of VSCode.